# Change padding in navigation bar anchors so that it takes maximum space available in justified list

Tags: html, css, navbar

What I want is for the whole area to be clickable. For that I would need to set padding of the anchor elements. However, just adding something like `ul li a{padding: 15px 15px;}` feels wrong to me, since on a FullHD screen I won't be able to cover the space in between `<li>` elements. How do I set the padding so that the `anchor` is effectively centered inside its parent `li` element?

I was thinking about using `ul{text-align:center;}`, but I couldn't think of a way to make them take maximum space and rearrange on resizing as nicely as `text-align:justify;` does.

What I have in mind as a goal is the following structure, kept same even with screen resizing:

|---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------| |---------Services---------|----------Products---------|----------Contact us----------|----------Webstore----------| |---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
Where the all of the area in between `|` is essentially padding - affected by background-color, clickable.

I want to use CSS/HTML without JS. Here is what I currently have: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z1v1wfnb/). While view on smaller screens could be dealt with better, it is not crucial enough.

Any kind of advice would be appreciated. I have looked over a lot of questions and answers, but couldn't find a solution combining the things that I have.

Comment: Cant you just put a percentage on the li's width? Or use the `display: table` and `display:table-cell` http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/XMkr6/

Comment: @JordyvanEijk I can. How do I make the padding of the anchor match the width of the list element?

Comment: just make the anchor `display:block;` this way you can give it a hieght and width of 100% to fill its parent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `display: table` and `display: table-cell`
where the `ul` is the table and the `li` is the table-cell

for more information about how to implement this check out [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/dosandk/XMkr6/)
And here is a link to the [update fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u5c2pvm8/4/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without padding. Just define the anchor elements as blocks, keep your list-items as `inline-block` and set a percent width on the list-item.

Then, make your anchors have centered text with 100% width and height. I have updated your original fiddle to illustrate this:
https://jsfiddle.net/z1v1wfnb/2/